# How to clear cells when another cell becomes empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a list of items and totaling each item's quantity and weight.

The name of the item goes in A1, the weight of goes in C1, and the quantity goes in D1.

E1 is a formula to calculate the total weight by multiplying C1 and D1.

When I clear the contents of an item in A1, I want to automatically clear the cells of C1 and D1, which in turn will clear the weight from E1 and the total of all items later in the page?

I'd like something that would repeat for specified cells from A1-A31, and that would work automatically when I delete a cell's contents and hit enter.

Comment: You need the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event to do this automatically. Good news is that it's pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Just like BigBen said, as it's not possible to write formulas into cells (C and D) and at the same time input data into them. And the macro would be a straightforward loop through the range A1-A31 with one conditional `If cellA is blank then clear cellC and cellD`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event to do this automatically, something like this:

Add the following code to that sheet's code module (right click on the sheet tab and hit *View Code* to bring it up):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A31")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A31"))
        If IsEmpty(rng) Then
            On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
        End If
    Next rng

ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```